# Creating a report based on the length of the array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm converting a report from PHP to jQuery.

Below is my PHP Code:

```
Morris.Donut({
      element: 'graph_donut',
      data: [
          <?php foreach ($result as $value) {?>
          {label: <?php echo $value->x;?>, value: <?php echo $value->y;?>},
          <?php } ?>
      ],
      resize: true
    });
```

**The variable $result could be any value from 1 to 4.**

I want to convert this to convert this to jQuery and I have the result in json format. However I'm not able to achieve what I had achieved easily in PHP. I do not have any issue if result.length is 4 but if it is less than 4 I get undefined error. Below is my code in js.

```
Morris.Donut({
      element: 'graph_donut',
      data: [
          {label: result[0].x, value: result[0].y},
          {label: result[1].x, value: result[1].y},
          {label: result[2].x, value: result[2].y},
          {label: result[3].x, value: result[3].y},
      ],
      resize: true
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the array before

```
data = [];
result.forEach(function(i) { data.push({label: i.x, value: i.y}) });
Morris.Donut({
      element: 'graph_donut',
      data: data,
      resize: true
    });
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/787596)**

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked like a charm. Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to build up the data based on the length of result instead of inserting it directly.

So something like this?

```js
results = [{"cat_name":"something","x":94},{"cat_name":"something else","x":6}];

data = results.map(function(result) {
  return {
    label: result.cat_name,
    value: result.x
  }
});

console.log(data)
```

Then use it like this,

```
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'graph_donut',
  data: data,
  resize: true
});
```

Comment: Here is my json result - [{"cat_name":"something","x":94},{"cat_name":"something else","x":6}]